# Keyword for 64 bit ineteger in Linux Assembly Programming

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, 64-bit

I am new to Linux Assembly Programming and running x86_64 Ubuntu 13.04 .
As far as i know . 
Registers in 64 bits are like this
rax - 64 bit 
eax - 32 bit
ax - 16 bit 
and again ah and al 8 bits

but int in both 32 and 64 bit OS are 32 bits i.e Int32.

so if i try to copy a int vaue in (say rax) it will take only eax ( if you know what i mean ) , my simple question is that WHAT KEYWORD(DATATYPE) IS USED FOR 64 BIT INTEGERS IN LINUX ASSEMBLY PROGRAMMING ?
like .int for 32 bit INETGER
i tried long , it's also using 32 bit , dont know why.
If you need any other info, reply below .

Comment: That's very assembler specific.  What toolchain are you using?

Comment: Simple assembling it using "as" with just -gstabs for debugging and then linking with "ld" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [`.quad`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Quad.html#Quad) directive.

Answer (score 1):

In NASM for example, the integral data types are named `BYTE`, `WORD`, `DWORD` and `QWORD`, e.g.:

```
mov  al,  BYTE PTR [ebx]    ; 1 byte
mov  ax,  WORD PTR [ebx]    ; 2 bytes
mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebx]    ; 4 bytes
mov rax, QWORD PTR [ebx]    ; 8 bytes
```

Other assembler dialects would also suffix the instructions (`movb`, `movs`, `movl`, `movq`), but in this version the type of the instruction is inferred from the operand size.

Strictly speaking, the pointer type is also redundant in this example, but other instructions (like move-with-zero-extension) really need to know explicitly how many bytes to read from memory, which is where the type names come in.